# How to get onclick="vm.$refs.foo.addThing()" working in Vue when calling from external JS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm trying to get my code which looks similar to this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fakezcmp/1/) working.

The code basically has `onclick="vm.$refs.foo.addThing()"` outside the Vue instance (I couldn't change the way it is) which calls a function in Vue's `methods`.

However, it's not working right now, and I don't get why it's like that.

**HomeView.vue**

```
var MyComponent = Vue.extend({
  template: '<div><p>Hello</p><ul><li v-for="thing in things">{{ thing }}</li></ul></div>',
  data: function() {
    return {
      things: ['first thing']
    };
  },
  methods: {
    addThing: function() {
        this.things.push('another thing ' + this.things.length);
    }
  }
});

var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
  'my-component': MyComponent
  }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="app">
<h1>Component Test</h1>
<my-component ref="foo"></my-component>
</div>

<button onclick="vm.$refs.foo.addThing()">External Button</button>
```

Comment: @Andrew1325 Not working because `<button> ...` is outside the Vue instace, aka, in the plain HTML (I can't change the way it is).

Comment: Oddly, that fiddle works fine in Codepen: https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/NeeEbm?editors=1010

Comment: if you link your js file at the end of the body this issue may not come.

Answer (score 0):

You could expose this method to the `window` object, but it's considered an anti-pattern and you should probably consider moving this button inside of the component somehow.

Or, use some hack:

```js
const MyComponent = Vue.extend({
  template: '<div><p>Hello</p><ul><li v-for="thing in things">{{ thing }}</li></ul></div>',
  data: function() {
    return {
      things: ['first thing']
    };
  },
  methods: {
    addThing: function() {
      this.things.push('another thing ' + this.things.length);
    }
  }
});

const vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  mounted() {
    var btn = document.getElementById('btn-external');

    btn.addEventListener('click', this.$refs.foo.addThing);
  },

  components: {
    'my-component': MyComponent
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <h1>Component Test</h1>
  <my-component ref="foo"></my-component>
</div>

<button id="btn-external">External Button</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access `$refs` before the template has been processed(Check [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram)).

Please take a look at the revised code: https://jsfiddle.net/b5oset1w/17/

Javascript:

```
var MyComponent = Vue.extend({
  template: '<div><p>Hello</p><ul><li v-for="thing in things">{{ thing }}</li></ul></div>',
  data: function() {
    return {
      things: ['first thing']
    };
  },
  methods: {
    addThing: function() {
      this.things.push('another thing ' + this.things.length);
    }
  }
});

var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    'my-component': MyComponent
  },
  mounted: function() {
    console.log(this.$refs)
  },
  methods: {
    onAddThing: function() {
      this.$refs.foo.addThing()
    }
  }
});
```

Template:

```
<div id="app">
  <h1>Component Test</h1>
  <my-component ref="foo"></my-component>

  <button @click="onAddThing">External Button</button>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

another approach to achieve this is creating a vue instance for external button also. like below sample code.

```js
    var MyComponent = Vue.extend({
        template: '<div><p>Hello</p><ul><li v-for="thing in things">{{ thing }}</li></ul></div>',
        data: function() {
            return {
                things: ['first thing']
            };
        },
        methods: {
            addThing: function() {
                this.things.push('another thing ' + this.things.length);
            }
        }
    });

    var vm = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        components: {
            MyComponent: MyComponent
        }
    });

        var vm1 = new Vue({
        el: '#newapp',
        methods:{
         clickAction:function(){
          vm.$refs.foo.addThing();
         }
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<h1>Component Test</h1>
<my-component ref="foo"></my-component>
</div>

<div id="newapp">
   <button @click="clickAction">External Button</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Unless you're going to have some other data and methods inside this *additional* instance of Vue (apart from the "external button"), I don't think that would be worth all the resources (e.g. having to go through the complete lifecycle hooks) spent.